# How to use Angular's filter without ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, filter

Use case: Using Angular, filter a list of dom nodes based on text match.

I have a list of dom nodes like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter section">
<section>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
</section>
```

I'd like to use Angular to filter down to just "foo". The problem that I'm facing is any Angular example of `filter` assumes the HTML is outputted via `ng-repeat`. My situation is the list within `<section>` above is being looped from the server.

So my question is pretty simple and likely silly, but: how can you apply Angular's `filter` utility so that list of nodes can be filtered using the `<input>`?

Comment: For reference, I know how to handle this pretty easily in jQuery. The question is more about trying to understand Angular's filter paradigm, especially as it relates to iterating and loops vs. static content.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no model here to apply the filter. So angular does not have an object to process.
You have 2 choices:

- write yourself a directive that does this work
- return the data as JSON and display it with ng-reapeat